# I want to build a regex which matches a particular string

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have a string

```
"CC/N/NAME ‡C/CITY NAME ‡A/ADDRESS"
```

i want to match exact same string. If the symbol `‡` comes in between of any valid char i.e `CC/N/NAME ‡C/CITY‡ NAME ‡A/ADDRESS"` than this whole string should not match. Also if string has `CC/\[NACZP\]/` so it should match.

I have tried this regex:

But it also matches ‡ symbol if it dosn't have `‡\[NACZP\]/` valid characters

```
^(CC\\/[NACZP]\\/[^‡]*)|(.*)(?<=‡[NACZP]\\/)([^‡]*)|^CC\\/[¤ ]$
```

I have tried this

```
^(CC\/[NACZP]\/[^‡]*)|(.*)(?<=‡[NACZP]\/)([^‡]*)|^CC\/[¤ ]$
```

and i am expecting that it should only match a valid string which has `CC/[NACZP]/` and if in middle of string we have ‡ so it should have `[NACZP]/` after that. i.e `‡N/NAME`.

Comment: Remove Java tag as this question is related to regex

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following pattern.
I don't believe a *look-around* would be necessary here, just repeated groups.

I'm not sure if I've matched your specifications exactly.
It appears to just be delimited, sequenced uppercase letters, which may be preceded by the double-dagger character, *‡*, only if they are a singular *N*, *A*, *C*, *Z*, or *P* letter.

```
^CC(?:/(?:‡[NACZP]|[A-Z]+)(?: ‡[NACZP]| [A-Z]+)*)*/?$
```

This will match the following.

```
CC
CC/
CC/N
CC/N/NAME
CC/N/NAME ‡C
CC/N/NAME ‡C/CITY NAME ‡A
CC/N/NAME ‡C/CITY NAME ‡A/ADDRESS
```

And, not these,

```
CC/ /
CC/ABC /
CC/ 123
CC/‡B
CC/‡A ‡B
CC/‡ABC
CC/CITY‡ NAME
CC/N/NAME ‡C/CITY‡ NAME ‡A/ADDRESS
```

As a note, you mention the following.

> *"... Also if string has CC/\[NACZP\]/ so it should match. ..."*

Which, I believe is a typo, in regard to `\[`, and `\]`.
Since, you are not checking for those, within your pattern.

```
\\/[NACZP]\\/
```